# Perl - Return last alpha character after last digit in a string and return modified string too

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like this:

```
$var = '123456d';
```

or possibly

```
$var = '123456'; # (no alpha char)
```

There will be up to 6 digits no less than 5 if that matters. 
No alpha, spaces or special mixed in the numbers.

In my Perl script, I need to remove and return the last alpha character AND the string without the alpha character.

I suppose can use \D and trim? or chop? but, there must be an easy way to get both vars quickly.

```
my $numbers =~   s/\D+?$var//;  #???  

my $alpha = substr($var, 0, -1); ## but no alpha check.
```

or

```
my $alpha = chop($var); ## but no alpha check.
```

then if a-Z and so on to check if it is an alpha character.

Or the limit of my ability solution:

```
$alpha = $var;
$alpha =~ s/[0-9]//ig;
$var =~ s/[a-Z]//ig;
$numbers = $var;
```

so result:

```
($numbers == '123456')
($alpha eq 'd') (or '' if nothing)
```

I feel like this is too trivial to ask here but, I just cannot find or write an applicable solution.

My use of =~ s is just a guess but, there must be a better way or even a one liner.

Thanks for all the help here...

SORRY after thought! There may be 2 alpha characters after the digits! They would need to be returned together as a single var ($alpha eq 'dd')

I found this too to0:

```
$var =~ s{^([0-9]+).*}{$1}i;
```

Comment: The range `[A-z]` is a grave error.  For an alpha character, you should write `\p{alpha}`, simply enough.

Comment: Thank you so $var =~ s/\p{alpha}//ig; ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `\pL` will avoid capturing numbers, and making the string optional will assure that the match happens even for numbers without ending letters.

```
my $var = '123456d';
my ($num, $letter) = $var =~ /^(\d+)(\pL)?$/;
```

Note that you cannot use `\w` to capture the possible ending letter, because it also includes numbers. As tchrist has pointed out, `\p{alpha}` can also be used.

Comment: I think I actually understand! I will try this and get right back to you.

Comment: Won't the `(\d+)` be greedy enough to prevent numbers from being captured at the end?  Or are you thinking input like "12345d3" ?

Comment: @RobI I assumed it was letters at the end. If it indeed can be numbers as well, some other method would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
my $numbers =~ s/(\d+)(\p{alpha}+)?/$1/;

my $alpha = $2;
```

The `$1` refers to the first parentheses capture, the `$2` refers to the second.

Edited: used `\d` for digit, `\p{alpha}` for alpha.

Comment: I’m afraid that’s inaccurate, in that `\w` is ***not*** alpha plus underscore. It is all alphabetics (including circled letters and such letter-numbers as Roman numerals), all combining marks, all numeric digits, and all connector punctuation. Anyway, if you want alpha, write `\p{alpha}`.

Comment: @tchrist I seem to recall you recommending `\pL` before.

Comment: @TLP Although there’s a difference between `\pL` and `\p{alpha}` in full technical definition (the latter includes the former, but much else besides), I imagine that `\pL` is what many people unfamiliar with the nitty-gritty are mostly looking for.

Comment: Thanks guys!  I updated to use \p{alpha}.  Either way is much better than my `[a-z]` I started with.  I don't tend to think internationally (yet)... Any guidance on using the `[[:alpha:]]` syntax?  It's POSIX but not international maybe?